How to navigate to a specific page
(use svelte and spring-boot)
I'm creating a Find ID screen.

In the "Find ID screen", the user enters the account information
Click the OK button to check the data to see if you actually have an account.
If the data match, go to the "ID Results Screen" with the id value.

Number 3 is the problem.
goto('/login/viewId?loginId=${loginId}`)

in the same manner as above
I put the id in the url and sent it to the result screen.
But I found out that id shouldn't be exposed to url.
As you move to a specific page, the url has a parameter value
Is there any way to make it so that it doesn't expose it?
I wonder if the controller should do the redirection.
(This is the code you wrote.)
    async function findId() {
        const formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('Form'));

            const response = await Api.post(`/login/IdCheck`, formData); // 1. ID Check
            if (response.data.resultCode == 'success') {
                var loginId = response.data.findInfo.loginId;

                goto(`./Id/IdDisplay?Id=${Id}`);// 2.Query String NO....
     
    }

How to navigate to a specific page

The issue you're facing is known as URL leakage, where sensitive information is exposed directly in the URL.
A good way to tackle this is to store the result in a session or local storage before redirecting the page.
If you need code, I can provide that.

@user24888148: Client-side state like the session/local storage are still accessible to attackers. If anything, store a temporary generated key that can be resolved on the server or associate the result with the a server-side session.

To be clear, after the user has logged in, the client needs to store some proof (e.g. session id, or an access token, etc.) that the user has logged in to a specific account. Your options are mostly global variable, session/local storage or a cookie. A global variable is probably the least dangerous one to use, but a cookie created with the HttpOnly and Secure flags is also common (used when you need to remember it between sessions).
